# Change html structure of all img tags in Wordpress

Tags: images, filters, regex, customization

I have a Wordpress blog and am trying to implement the [foresight.js](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js) image script. In short, I need to target all post images, swap out the `src, width, & height` attributes with `data-src, data-width, & data-height` attributes. I then need to duplicate the image line and wrap it in `<noscript>` tags. This is the structure I'm trying to have Wordpress generate/create:

```
<img data-src="wordpress/image/url/pic.jpg" data-width="{get width of image with PHP & pass-in that value here} data-height="{get height of image with PHP and pass-in that value here}" class="fs-img">
<noscript>
    <img src="wordpress/image/url/pic.jpg">
</noscript>
```

I have searched the Wordpress codex and the best possible route I can find are to use filters (ie. *'get_image_tag'* & *'image_tag'*) for modifying the html that Wordpress outputs for each image. I'm thinking that one of these options should work, or that I can do some pattern matching with regex *(I know, not ideal)*, throw in a `preg_replace` and then inject this back into `the_content` filter.

I have tried some of these options but cannot get any to work. Could someone please offer some help? Found one suggestion [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-change-img-tag-html/), but can't even get it to work!

#### 'get_image_tag' attempt:

*Found this particular one on the web, but it would need modified to fit my logic (see above structure)...can't make sense of what the `preg_replace` array is doing on my own.*

```
<?php function image_tag($html, $id, $alt, $title) {
    return preg_replace(array(
        '/'.str_replace('//','\/\/',get_bloginfo('url')).'/i',
        '/\s+width="\d+"/i',
        '/\s+height="\d+"/i',
        '/alt=""/i'
    ),
    array(
        '',
        '',
        '',
        alt='"' . $title . '"'
    ),
    $html);
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'image_tag', 0, 4);
?>
```

#### Another 'get_image_tag' attempt:

```
<?php function get_image_tag($id, $alt, $title, $align, $size='full') {
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img_src);
    $hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height);

    $class = 'align' . esc_attr($align) . ' size-' . esc_attr($size) . ' wp-image-' . $id;
    $class = apply_filters('get_image_tag_class', $class, $id, $align, $size);

    $html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" title="' . esc_attr($title).'" data-width="' . $width . '" data-height="' . $height . '" class="' . $class . ' fs-img" />';
    $html = apply_filters( 'get_image_tag', $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size);

    return $html;
}
?>
```

#### Pattern-matching attempt:

Tried creating my own regex on this one, but not sure if it's correct.

```
<?php function restructure_imgs($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern = "/<img(.*?)src=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)(|\")(.*?)>/i";

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($2$3.$4$5);
    $hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height);

    $replacement = '<img$1data-src=$2$3.$4$5 title="'.$post->post_title.'" data-width="'.$width.'" data-height="'.$height.'" class="fs-img"$6>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'restructure_imgs');
?>
```

Unfortunately can't get any of these examples to work. Any help or sharing your pre-written scripts/functions would be much appreciated! Thanks for helping a student learn!!

Answer (score 8):

The filters you are trying to use run on **image insertion**, so it is not possible to swap all the images already present in your posts using these filters. It should work, however, if you intend to change to `img` tags *from now on*.

The filter [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), however, is applied to the post after it is retrieved from the database and before displaying it to screen. I believe that, in order to make a change to your existing posts without reinserting the images, you could use this filter.

You can parse `the_content` using the [PHP DOMDocument class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). When it comes to HTML parsing in PHP, [**do not use regex**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

I wrote a sample function for what you want to do, it's a bit verbose in order to explain the passages. Feel free to tweak it at will.

```
<?php
function foresight_hires_img_replace($the_content) {
    // Create a new istance of DOMDocument
    $post = new DOMDocument();
    // Load $the_content as HTML
    $post->loadHTML($the_content);
    // Look up for all the <img> tags.
    $imgs = $post->getElementsByTagName('img');

    // Iteration time
    foreach( $imgs as $img ) {
        // Let's make sure the img has not been already manipulated by us
        // by checking if it has a data-src attribute (we could also check
        // if it has the fs-img class, or whatever check you might feel is
        // the most appropriate.
        if( $img->hasAttribute('data-src') ) continue;

        // Also, let's check that the <img> we found is not child of a <noscript>
        // tag, we want to leave those alone as well.
        if( $img->parentNode->tagName == 'noscript' ) continue;

        // Let's clone the node for later usage.
        $clone = $img->cloneNode();

        // Get the src attribute, remove it from the element, swap it with
        // data-src
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        $img->removeAttribute('src');   
        $img->setAttribute('data-src', $src);

        // Same goes for width...
        $width = $img->getAttribute('width');
        $img->removeAttribute('width');
        $img->setAttribute('data-width', $width);

        // And height... (and whatever other attribute your js may need
        $height = $img->getAttribute('height');
        $img->removeAttribute('height');
        $img->setAttribute('data-height', $height);

    // Get the class and add fs-img to the existing classes
        $imgClass = $img->getAttribute('class');
        $img->setAttribute('class', $imgClass . ' fs-img');

        // Let's create the <noscript> element and append our original
        // tag, which we cloned earlier, as its child. Then, let's insert
        // it before our manipulated element
        $no_script = $post->createElement('noscript');
        $no_script->appendChild($clone);
        $img->parentNode->insertBefore($no_script, $img);
    };

     return $post->saveHTML();
 }

 add_filter('the_content', 'foresight_hires_img_replace');
 ?>
```

I didn't test it specifically with Wordpress, but I tested it with a sample post output and it should work.

Comment: While reading, I realized that you wanted the `<noscript>` tag to be after your manipulated `<img>`; in order to do that, if it is of any importance, you might want to swap the cloning I did (manipulate `$clone`, not `$img`) as there is no such `insertAfter()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This code works very well for me, but I had some issues during the process to get the final version.

**Warning**

The first is that the server started showing some warnings like `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819603/dom-loadhtml-doesnt-work-properly-on-a-server) shows more details of the error and how to solve it, but to add, adding this `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` code at main function before calling `loadHTML` fix the problem.

The second (group of) problem was with the method [DOMDocument::loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

**Character encoding**

The documentation has a [very important comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95463) from Shane Harte about character encoding of UTF-8 documents. So, before `loadHTML` I had to use `[mb_convert_encoding][4]` with `'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"` parameters.

**HTML wrapper**

The second problem with the method was that the output always contained a doctype + HTML + body tags and in this case, this is a huge problem because you are dealing with only one clipping of the document (`the_content()`) and not the whole.

The simplest way to fix this is to use libxml constants as parameters of the loadHTML method

> **LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED** turns off the automatic adding of implied
>   html/body elements 
>   **LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD** prevents a default doctype
>   being added when one is not found.

Something like `$output->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($the_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

**Unexpected end first tag of `the_content()`**

Another problem I started to see was that the tag of the **first element** of "the_content" was not closed properly.

For example, if the first element was a `<p>`, the entire content of `the_content` was wrapped by that first `<p>`. In many cases, the content started with an H2, then it had the same issue.

After a lot of research, I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36547335/9028206) of Nicholas Shanks that opened my mind:

> LibXML requires a root node and is treating the first element it finds as the root node, deleting the (incorrectly located) closing tag it finds half-way through and then outputting the closing tag of the first element is found at the end of the document.

So, the first part of my code looks like this:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$encode_content = mb_convert_encoding($the_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$post = new DOMDocument();
$workarround = '<section class="sanitized-content">'. $encode_content . '</section>';
$post->loadHTML( $workarround, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
```

✌️

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fixes!