# the_content() printing DOCTYPE, <html> and <body> tags in the middle of page

Tags: plugins, php, page-template, html, the-content

I'm building a custom Wordpress theme and I've just come across a bizarre issue where the_content() seems to be printing out the page content wrapped in the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body> ... </body></html>
```

This is an issue because I've now got second instances of DOCTYPE, html and body tags appearing in my page code. I've attached screenshots below showing the code and the output.

I would appreciate any help as to why this may be happening and how I can go about solving the problem. I've disabled all plugins so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

[image: Code]

[image]

**Edit:** The content was copy and pasted directly from another webpage and it has been suggested that this was the source of the DOCTYPE and tags. I have removed all this content and manually inputted some text and the tags still exist as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Does that happen with a default Twenty-X theme?

Comment: It's a custom theme I'm developing at the moment

Comment: Are you sure the doctype and HTML tags are not just inside the content of that post?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: following up on Jacob's comment: did you type the content into the editor or did you use copy/paste from a web source?

Comment: The DOCTYPE and html tags are not just inside the content of that post. I did copy and paste the content into the editor from a web source, however I've just put the same text into a plain .txt file to remove any possible formatting and readded it to the post and the tags are still appearing.

Comment: I had a lot of similar problems and shared how to solve in that answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/359202/183124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, this solution is very particular to my case but maybe it can help point somebody else in the right direction in the future if they encounter a similar problem.

I have a custom function that adds a CSS class for lazy-loading images into all `<img>` tags that are present in the_content().

In this function I am using the following code:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML( utf8_decode( $content ) );
```

The DOCTYPE, html tags and body tags were appearing because of PHP's loadHTML method.

Changing the above code to the following has solved this issue.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML( utf8_decode( $content ), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
```

I found the details I needed to solve this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper

Comment: I was using loadHTML for a different reason, but this solved my problem. Thanks!